# Partial Collinearity in Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I had a doubt about the effect of multi-colinearity in regression analysis. I understand if two variables are co-related we cannot disentangle the effects of one from the other on the target variable thus the coefficient we give them is not optimal.

However, what happens in the cause of 0.8 co-linearity or 0.6 or such? There are situations within the dataset where the model has the information to disentangle each's effects. A human would look at those causes to first to do so. The places where they are uncorrelated (i.e opposite directions from their own means) should convey the true relationship, right?

For high co-linearity like 0.9+ I was thinking the cases where they are uncorrelated would seem like noise to the model for eg) If I always saw two people together and didn't see them once, I thought this is an outlier or not representative.

I have done linear regression in machine learning where we use gradient descent but just not learning the more theoretical aspects of it. If we were fitting a flexible non-linear function to the case of 0.8 co-linearity, I guess it would be able to model it correctly....

Comment: As you might know, there is a geometrical interpretation of ordinary least squares regression in terms of analyzing one side of a triangle as a vector sum of two other sides.  When the other two sides are perpendicular, the Pythagorean Theorem asserts the squared length of the original side can be split into the sum of squares of the other two.  What you are asking is whether this can ever be done in non-right triangles.  I hope that picture of the situation gives you a convincing intuition about the answer.